# Uncheck parent node if all children unchecked in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to uncheck parent node if all children are unchecked.

```
<ul id="treeList">
   <li>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
   Application Manager
    <ul>
       <li>
           <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
           Application Manager Panel
       </li>
       <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
            Client Role
             <ul>
               <li>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
                   Client Task 1
                </li>
                <li>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
                    Client Task 2
                </li>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
```

I have following jQuery script. But when I uncheck any children, the parent got uncheck. It should see, if all children are unchecked. then it should uncheck the parent.

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('#treeList ul li').find(':checkbox'),  function(){
    jQuery(this).change(function (){
        if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
            jQuery(this).parents('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }else{
            jQuery(this).parents('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        }        
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unchecking the parent `li` checkbox every time you uncheck a child, instead of checking if there's still some other checked items. Instead, you could check the number of items `checked` and use that `length` as a `boolean`:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('#treeList ul li').find(':checkbox'),  function(){
    jQuery(this).change(function (){
        if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
                      jQuery(this).parentsUntil('#treeList').siblings().filter('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true).trigger('change');
        }else{                
            jQuery(this).parents('ul:first').siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).parent().siblings().children('input:checked').length).trigger('change');
        }        
    });    
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/fRxVs/

Here is your fiddle's updated version... added some CSS to clarify the Tree Level (Parent and Child Relationship ) http://jsfiddle.net/vimalpatel/fRxVs/440/

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. If I have another node like Client Role and further it can also has 2 Client Task in it. Any hint on it? Because it does not work on the Sibling nodes of Client Role.

Comment: @Tahir Akram Made a small update to the code, should work as intended now.

Comment: A). Check Client Task 2 (very last node)
B). Uncheck Client Task2. It will Uncheck Client Role. But Application Manager (The top node) will remain checked. [Issue]

Comment: @Tahir Akram forcing `trigger` change should resolve it. Updated example.

Comment: @TahirAkram Here is your fiddle's updated version... added some CSS to clarify the Tree Level (Parent and Child Relationship ) http://jsfiddle.net/vimalpatel/fRxVs/440/

Answer (score 1):

Here you have:

```
$("#treeList :checkbox").change(function(){
         uncheckParentIfSiblingsUnchecked($(this));
      });
      function uncheckParentIfSiblingsUnchecked($chk){
         if($chk.size() == 1 && !$chk.is(":checked")){
            $checked_siblings = $chk.closest("ul").children("li").children(":checkbox:checked");
            if($checked_siblings.size() == 0){
                 $parent_checkbox = $chk.closest("ul").prev(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
                 uncheckParentIfSiblingsUnchecked($parent_checkbox);
            }
         }
      }
```

It's recursive cause it must 'bubble' to the root checkbox.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Edgar, the code does not work for me. PS: I am not the down voter.