# Dynamically check / uncheck checkboxes in a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tree

I have a similar question to [Uncheck parent node if all children unchecked in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556446/uncheck-parent-node-if-all-children-unchecked-in-jquery/6556519#6556519) (with this solution) and have tried to modify it so that the children will also all uncheck if the parent is unchecked (which the above/below fails to do).

JSFiddle for the above (http://jsfiddle.net/fRxVs/)

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('#treeList ul li').find(':checkbox'),  function(){
    jQuery(this).change(function (){
        if (jQuery(this).is(':checked')) {
                      jQuery(this).parentsUntil('#treeList').siblings().filter('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true).trigger('change');
        }else{

            jQuery(this).parents('ul:first').siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).parent().siblings().children('input:checked').length).trigger('change');
        }        
    });    
});
```

Though I'm not sure why, but I had to change `prop` from the last line to `attr` in order for it to correctly work as JSFiddle locally for some reason...

Basically I have a 3 level setup:

```
Grand-Parent
- Parent
-- Child
```

- If the `grandparent` is checked/unchecked, then its children and grandchildren should all be checked/unchecked too.
- If the `parent` is checked/unchecked, its children should be checked/unchecked as well as its parent.
- If the `children` are checked, then its parent and grandparent should be checked (if no children are checked then parent shouldn't be checked).

I'm trying to change this to Continent, Country, Region - I think you will understand if I were to just say this....

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question on Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/nested-select-all-checkboxes/5038#5038

Comment: Just took a look at that, and tried the JSFiddle for it - but that only makes the child's parent check if both (I imagine it ends up being all) children have been checked - I'd like it so that just one child feeds up the tree.

Comment: I'm having a look at it. I've just optimized the code, moving onwards to fixing it ;)

Comment: Thanks @RobW! Look forward to seeing your solution, hope I can increase my understanding of jQuery through it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution: **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fRxVs/55/**

```
$('#treeList :checkbox').change(function (){
    $(this).siblings('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).parentsUntil('#treeList', 'ul').siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).parentsUntil('#treeList', 'ul').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var childSelected = $this.find(':checkbox:checked').length;
            if (!childSelected) {
                $this.prev(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

### Modifications and explanations

- `$` is exactely the same as `jQuery`. Be consistent when using it: `jQuery` should only be used when you're not sure whether `$ === jQuery` (is `$` overwritten?).
- `:checkbox` is a selector which matches every `input[type="checkbox"]`. It's obsolete to specify `input:checbkox`, since a checkbox element is always an input element.
- `.find(..)` seeks for any element which is a child (not necessery the direct child) of the matched selector. `"#treeList :checkbox"` is faster, and has the equivalent result as `$('#treeList').find(':checkbox')`.
- When a property/method/event is added to a jQuery object, all elements which match the selector will be modified. Therefore, you don't have to loop through each element individually: `jQuery.each(jQuery('#treeList :checkbox'), function(){ jQuery(this).change(...)})` can be shortened to `jQuery('#treeList :checkbox').change(...)`.
- You don't have to trigger `change` after changing a checkbox check state, because the function already takes care of the full tree.

Comment: Nice one! Though I just noticed that if you check 2 'parents', then uncheck one, the 'grandparent' unchecks, can this be modified so that the grandparent only unchecks if no parent is checked?

Comment: Make that when I uncheck each child, rather than unchecking the parent

Comment: The explanations were great by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Old question but you could just do it like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    $(this).next().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $(this).parents('ul').prev('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function(){
        return $(this).next().find(':checked').length;
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ojc1qg1f/