# Category and blog post tree structure in PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, tree

I am trying to mimic the functionality of the image below.  I am working on a wordpress blog and I need to be able to put blog post into a tree structure underneath categories

I only need to go 3 levels deep at most

```
Category 1  
- blog post  
- blog post  
- SUB-CATEGORY
--- blog post
--- blog post
CATEGORY 2
- SUB-CATEGORY
--- blog post
--- blog post
- SUB-CATEGORY2
--- blog post
--- blog post
- SUB-CATEGORY3
--- blog post
--- blog post
```

I am lost on where to even begin, can anyone point me in the right direction on where to begin?

Using PHP, MySQL, Javascript.  I would like to have the categories and sub-categories be able to be collapsed and expanded which I can do with javascript and when you click an actual blog post it should load it into a frame or window beside the tree

[image]

Comment: I have previously answered a question regarding a tree-view, in JavaScript. Get some inspiration at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965531/check-uncheck-tree-with-toggle-slide-few-minor-coding-issues/7967528#7967528

Comment: JQuery is always the solution: appendTo() to create the tree and toggle() to show/hide them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Wordpress plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dtree-30/. They have an example site at http://game.hgo.se/cat/projects/3d-games/.

Comment: Thank you that will save me hours i'm sure

Comment: If you want to recreate it, you can see their development source code on the Wordpress site by clicking Other Versions ». I haven't checked if there's a difference.